# Make the camera app save picture to the default directory

Tags: android, android-camera

Is there a way to launch the "take picture" Intent and make the camera app save the picture to the default file path? In other words, the picture should be saved to the same file as if the user launched the camera app manually and took a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Comment: That's not the dir where the camera stores pictures by default.

Comment: are you looking for the DCIM dir?

Comment: I want the camera app to save the photo to the same file path (not just the dir) as if the user launched the camera app manually and took a photo. On my phone, it's in the DCIM dir for example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's DCIM on every phone and has been for as long as I can remember so you could set up a nested loop to make sure that the DCIM directory exists and then set it as a shared preference so it only has to do it once and then will remember the location and write to it that way?

Comment: I doubt that all camera apps store photos into the DCIM/Camera folder and use the same file-naming scheme.

Comment: DCIM stands for Digital Camera IMages and is the recommended way of making an image storage directory, as for the "/camera" you could just check if it's there and if not check if the dcim directory has images in it. The naming convention will change from device to device but given that the methods for taking images are all`private native` I don't thing you will be able to call them. For more on the DCIM system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system

Comment: The fact that /Camera exists doesn't mean that the camera app will save he photos there. But I decided to save the photos to /Pictures/MyAppName and use my own file naming scheme.